# Write Arabic abstract that contains English words in Latin document

Tags: languages, arabic, abstract, resume, arabtex

I'm writing my these and I would like to insert an arabic Abstract following the same way for the French and English abstract as shown in the code bellow :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french, openright, oneside, fleqn]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Abstrait}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{

French text pararaph. Bla bla bla. The End.

}
}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Mots clés} : \\ Bla, Bla-bla.
\end{center}

% ***********
    
\newpage
\chapter*{Abstract}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{

English Text Pragraph. Bla bla bla. The End.

}
}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Keywords} : \\ Bla, Bla-Bla.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is the text that I would like to insert that contains some English words :

> مع ظهور تقنيات اتصالات جديدة مثل 5G ، تتطلب أنظمة وشبكات الاتصالات من
> الجيل التالي موثوقية عالية. يعتبر الراديو عبر تقنية الألياف أحد أفضل
> الخيارات ، والتي يمكن أن تستفيد من مزايا الألياف الضوئية (توهين منخفض
> ، نطاق ترددي عالي (THz) ، مسافة طويلة ، إلخ). في هذه الحالة ، نحتاج
> إلى استخدام أنواع أخرى من التشكيل ، والتي لها كفاءة طيفية عالية (SE) ،
> وسعة عالية ، وسرعة تتعامل مع جيجابت / ثانية وأداء عالي. الهدف من هذه
> الأطروحة هو اقتراح وتحليل أداء الراديو عبر أنظمة الألياف المستخدمة
> للتعايش بين شبكات الوصول اللاسلكي 5G الأمامية و FTTH على أساس استخدام
> الاستقطاب المزدوج للتشكيلات الرقمية مثل DP-QPSK و DP-QAM و DP-OFDM
> باستخدام تقنية WDM. نظريًا ، سيتم تنفيذ هذا العمل عن طريق التحليل
> الرياضي لنظامنا ، والذي سيكتب تقريرًا بحثيًا عن هذا النوع من التعديل
> وسيستخدم برنامج Optisystem للمحاكاة لتقييم موثوقية النظام بناءً على
> مخطط كوكبة ، مخطط العين ، BER ، SNR ، عامل Q ، إلخ.

I tried to use the `arabtex` package but seems to not work. Can you help me guys please ?

Comment: Sometimes it could be more practical, as an option, to insert a PDF page or an image of the text, with `\includepdf` (from `pdfpages` package) or `\includegraphics` (from `graphicx` package).

Comment: I couldn't get the `babel` settings correct for the paragraph alignment unless Arabic was the main language. This is a good example where part of one document can be imported into another.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in `babel`, as you originally did.  Here is a variant of the Arabic template I normally use.  It requires LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later, or will compile in XeLaTeX with a few warnings.

Your sample text might not have copied and pasted correctly into my editor, but I left it as is, because you’ll replace it with whatever you choose anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french, english, openright, oneside, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[main=english, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import]{arabic} % Could also choose a regional variant.

\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase, Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Sans}
% Set up Arabic sans-serif font here if needed, e.g. Noto Sans Arabic.
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{french=french}
\babeltags{Arabic=arabic}

\begin{document}

\begin{french}
\chapter*{Abstrait}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{

French text pararaph. Bla bla bla. The End.

}
}
\end{french}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Mots clés} : \\ Bla, Bla-bla.
\end{center}

% ***********
    

\newpage
\chapter*{Abstract}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{

English Text Paragraph. Bla bla bla. The End.

}
}

\begin{Arabic}
\newpage
\chapter*{\arabicabstractname}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{
    مع ظهور تقنيات اتصالات جديدة مثل 5G ، تتطلب أنظمة وشبكات الاتصالات من الجيل التالي موثوقية عالية. يعتبر الراديو عبر تقنية الألياف أحد أفضل الخيارات ، والتي يمكن أن تستفيد من مزايا الألياف الضوئية (توهين منخفض ، نطاق ترددي عالي (THz) ، مسافة طويلة ، إلخ). في هذه الحالة ، نحتاج إلى استخدام أنواع أخرى من التشكيل ، والتي لها كفاءة طيفية عالية (SE) ، وسعة عالية ، وسرعة تتعامل مع جيجابت / ثانية وأداء عالي. الهدف من هذه الأطروحة هو اقتراح وتحليل أداء الراديو عبر أنظمة الألياف المستخدمة للتعايش بين شبكات الوصول اللاسلكي 5G الأمامية و FTTH على أساس استخدام الاستقطاب المزدوج للتشكيلات الرقمية مثل DP-QPSK و DP-QAM و DP-OFDM باستخدام تقنية WDM. نظريًا ، سيتم تنفيذ هذا العمل عن طريق التحليل الرياضي لنظامنا ، والذي سيكتب تقريرًا بحثيًا عن هذا النوع من التعديل وسيستخدم برنامج Optisystem للمحاكاة لتقييم موثوقية النظام بناءً على مخطط كوكبة ، مخطط العين ، BER ، SNR ، عامل Q ، إلخ.
}
}
\end{Arabic}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Keywords} : \\ Bla, Bla-Bla.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus-Amiri sample]

The English abbreviations in the Arabic paragraph are being rendered in Amiri, but the font is a near-match for Khaled Hosny’s other font, Libertinus Serif.  If you still want to change it, you can write, for example, `\textenglish{5G}`.

You might consider turning the abstract formatting into a macro.  It is possible to redefine captions, such as `\abstractname`, in the current language.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, this is very useful, however it doesn't work with me. I copiated the hole code in a new project and I got errors in compilation. By the way, I'm working with LaTeX on Overleaf.

Comment: @SidiMohamedMerzougui Set the version of TeX Live to 2020 or later, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`Polylgossia` package might help. The output appears usable - I do not know Arabic (or Greek).

To have Latin and Arabic scripts together, you will need a font with both, like Amiri. Save the file in utf-8 format. `inputenc` and `fontenc` is not needed with xelatex or lualatex.

Compiled with xelatex.

From Wikipedia:

[image: abstract example]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic,greek}
\newfontface\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontface\greekfont[Colour=blue,Script=Greek]{Noto Serif}


\title{Eguzki-sistema}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The Solar System[b] is the gravitationally bound system of the Sun and the objects that orbit it, either directly or indirectly.[c]
\medskip

\begin{greek}
Το ηλιακό σύστημα περιλαμβάνει τον Ήλιο και όλα τα αντικείμενα τα οποία κινούνται σε τροχιά γύρω από αυτόν μέσα στο πεδίο βαρύτητάς του, είτε περιστρεφόμενα άμεσα γύρω από αυτόν είτε κινούμενα σε τροχιές γύρω από άλλα σώματα που κινούνται γύρω από τον Ήλιο.
\end{greek}

\begin{Arabic}

النظام الشمسي أو المجموعة الشمسية أو المنظومة الشمسية هي النظام الكوكبي الذي يتكون من الشمس وجميع ما يَدور حولها من أجرام بما في ذلك الأرض والكواكب الأخرى. يَشمل النظام الشمسي أجراماً أخرى أصغر حجماً هي الكواكب القزمة والكويكبات والنيازك والمذنبات، إضافة إلى سحابة رقيقة من الغاز والغبار تعرف بالوسط بين الكوكبي، كما توجد توابع الكواكب التي تسمى الأقمار، والتي يَبلغ عددها أكثر من 150 قمراً معروفاً في النظام الشمسي، 
\end{Arabic}


\end{abstract}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```